# fibonacci generator in D with std.concurrency.Generator

Tags: d

I need to write a Fibonacci series (starting from a,b) generator in D,
I've looked at the example here:

https://dlang.org/library/std/concurrency/generator.html

```
import std.concurrency;
import std.stdio;


void main()
{
    auto tid = spawn(
{
        while (true)
        {
           writeln(receiveOnly!int());
        }
    });

    auto r = new Generator!int(
    {
        foreach (i; 1 .. 10)
            yield(i);
    });

    foreach (e; r)
    {
        tid.send(e);
    }
}
```

But now I have no idea how to call the generator I wrote:

```
import std.concurrency;
import std.stdio;
import std.conv;
import std.string;

void main()
{
    writeln("Enter a then b");
    auto a_str = readln.strip;
    auto b_str = readln.strip;
    int a = to!int(a_str,16);
    int b = to!int(b_str,16);


    auto tid = spawn(
    {
        while (true)
        {
            writeln(receiveOnly!int());
        }
    });

    auto fib = new Generator!int(
    {
            yield(a);
            yield(b);
            while(true){
            int temp = b;
            b = a+b;
            a = temp;
            yield(b);
            }
    });

}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over the generator with a `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (n; fib) {
    writefln("%d\n", n);
}
```

In your case, it would keep yielding forever, so for test purposes you could set a counter.

BTW, I am also taking the same course :)